# searching for german quotes

Tags: regex, python-3.7

How do I check for open and close german quote? It simple does not work:

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

## problem: match of „

import re

test = u" „Hallo Welt“ "

if re.match(r"“", test):
    print("close quote")

if re.match(r"„", test):
    print("open quote")

The idle shell prints NOTHING.

Comment: Do not use `u` prefix in Python 3.x, it is default. And use `re.search` to look for a match anywhere inside a string.

Comment: It is re.search !!!